# How did this spam question get into HNQ?

Tags: discussion, bug

[This](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/147102/what-can-be-the-strategy-to-build-a-design-system) thread seems to be spam — the answer appears to be given by another account of OP ("Ashwin" vs "ash ux win") within 1.5 minutes of asking and the answerer promotes a resource in response to a very open question. Nothing special, I flagged it.

But the strange thing is that I stumbled across this question from the HNQ

[image]

And because of that I wanted to bring additional attention to it. How did it even happen that a question with just a few votes became hot? Views? Can anything be done to make it harder to game the HNQ system for promotion?

Comment: Maybe the names are just coincidences. Of course you will need a moderator to truly determine if a stockpuppet is being used or not.

Comment: @HenryWHHackv3.0 [Here's](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/147109/94310) another case of them posting within 2 minutes.